# what types are best for elasticsearch "KEYWORDS"(like hashtags) field?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7, elasticsearch-analyzers

i want to make Elasticsearch index for something KEYWORDS, like.. hashtag.
and make synonym filter for KEYWORDs.

i think two ways indexing keyword, first is make `keyword` type.

```
{
    "settings": {
        "keywordField": {
            "type": "keyword"
        }
    }
}
```

if make a index with `League of Legends`
maybe this.

```
{
    "keywordField": ["leagueoflegends", "league", "legends", "lol" /* synonym */]
}
```

or `text` type:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "keywordField": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "lowercase_and_whitespace_and_synonym_analyzer"
        }
    }
}
```

maybe this.

```
{
    "keywordField": ["league of legends"](synonym: lol => leagueoflegends)
}
```

if use `_analyzer` api for this field, expects "leagueoflegends", "league", "legends"

search query: 'lol', 'league of legends', 'League of Legends' have to match this field.

which practice is best?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query, and search result. In the below example, I have taken two synonyms `lol` and `leagueoflegends`

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {
          "synonym_filter": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "synonyms": [
              "leagueoflegends, lol"
            ]
          }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "synonym_analyzer": {
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "synonym_filter"
            ],
            "tokenizer": "standard"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "keywordField": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
    "keywordField": ["leagueoflegends", "league", "legends"]
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
 {
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "keywordField": {
        "query": "lol",
        "analyzer": "synonym_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "66872989",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.19363807,
        "_source": {
          "keywordField": [
            "leagueoflegends",
            "league",
            "legends"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```